# Trying to run systrace on android device but the resulting html shows an error

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0, systrace

Unable to select a master clock domain because no path can be found from "SYSTRACE" to "LINUX_FTRACE_GLOBAL".

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue. Mac OSX 10.14. tianrui yang answer did not resolve issue. Further experimentation showed issue only occurs on older api versions (<=21)

Comment: I am getting the same problem on my API level 22 device. I see a couple messages in logcat that say `BnListenService::onTransact received unrecognized msg 1599295570` from mediaserver process. Systrace however is working on my API level 26 device.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

open chrome, enter "chrome://tracing", and click the "load" button to load your trace html file.

Answer (score 1):

It might be used incorrectly parameters in systrace. The correct command is here, please try it.

```
python ./systrace.py -t 5 -o ./trace.html gfx input view webview wm am sm audio video camera hal app res dalvik rs bionic power sched irq freq idle disk mmc load sync workq memreclaim regulators
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `systrace` of catapult project, not in Android SDK worked for me.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/catapult-project/catapult.git
$ ./catapult/systrace/bin/systrace
```

For more info: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9AeXMVUUk3I&t=270